# Pyinstaller imported code cannot load images

Tags: python, tkinter, pyinstaller

I have a game set up in several files like so: `menu.py` `main.py`

I use Tkinter module. All needed files are bundled with the .EXE correctly, and are always called with `resource_path('folder/myImage.png')`

`menu.py` has no problem, but when `main.py` is executed, files are not loaded correctly(*error: no such file or directory*)

`menu.py` runs `main.py` by importing it(issue here?)

Other than that, I am clueless regarding the issue..

Thanks in advance

Comment: You used a relative path for your image. Is folder/myImage.png located in the same directory as menu.py or main.py?

Comment: yes, main.py and menu.py are in the same folder. I even tried to copy the line that showed the error in main.py into menu.py, no problem there..

Comment: if it will be of any significance, the code is here: https://github.com/Mato098/Bomberman .spec file for building .exe included

Comment: I think it's because you've defined your resource_path inside of a function in main_multiplayer.py, and functions in an imported module are not invoked on import. Only top-level code is run automatically. You'll probably want to import that function from main_multiplayer.py into the startup.py file and then invoke the resource_path function in the startup.py file for the path from the imported file to work.

Comment: thanks for your solution, though I am not going to implement your solution, as I have just realized that I can put the .exe file in the same directory as the resources and it will work just fine without needing to pack them into .exe

Comment: Ah, okay. That sounds good. I'm glad it worked out.